# What is the proper bash method of prompting the user for administrative password before backing up the usb data to the computer?

Tags: bash, terminal, usb, rsync, backup

```
mate-terminal --window-with-profile=PROFILENAME="Hold the terminal open" -e "sudo rsync -azvu --log-file=/var/log/simplebackup.log --append-verify --exclude '.gvfs' /media/user/usb/ /home/user/usbbackup/ ; read line ; read line"
```

I wrote the following one line bash script to prompt the user for a password before saving the usb data to the computer. I ran into a few problems:

(1) The terminal immediately closes after the command is executed, or maybe if it encounters an error.

(2) Rsync seems to either take way too long verifying the data or simply overwrites data regardless of its preexistence.

(3) How does one expand a one liner in a bash file for more readability?

(4) I am still figuring out how to automate this bash script when the usb is mounted.

What is the proper bash method of prompting the user for administrative password before backing up the usb data to the computer?

Comment: to expand one line command in to multiple lines.. press return at `;` though here its not going to help a lot

Answer (score 0):

sudo would seem to fit in this case. sudo for terminal (cli) commands and something like gksu for gui commands is pretty standard.

The problems your having probably have noting to do with how you choose to elevate permissions. For example, holding the terminal open is the job of the emulator, and has noting to do with bash.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, my very long command gksu --login rsync... failed with the error gksu: invalid option -- 'z'